# disable autoplay on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, android, autoplay

I would like to disable the autoplay of audio streaming from my website, the problem is that mobile devices do not work the autoplay and the button that activates the event is paused (as if you were playing audio). I wish that instead of the pause button play button appears and I think it best to disable the autoplay on mobile devices.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var audio, playbtn, mutebtn, seek_bar;
function initAudioPlayer(){
    audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = "http://listen.streaming";
    audio.loop = true;
    audio.play();
    // Set object references
    playbtn = document.getElementById("playpausebtn");
    // Add Event Handling
    playbtn.addEventListener("click",playPause);
    // Functions
    function playPause(){
        if(audio.paused){
            audio.play();
            playbtn.style.background = "url(pausa-sobre.png) no-repeat";
        } else {
            audio.pause();
            playbtn.style.background = "url(play-sobre.png) no-repeat";
        }
    }

}
window.addEventListener("load", initAudioPlayer);


    </script>
```

html

```
<button id="playpausebtn"></button>
```

CSS

```
    button{ border:none; cursor:pointer; outline:none; }
button#playpausebtn{
    background:url(pausa-sobre.png) no-repeat;
    width:68px;
    height:68px;
}
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML related to the player and play/pause button.

Comment: I edit the post, sorry. Thanks

Comment: Autoplay is disabled by default on mobile :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to check the `paused` status of the audio after you run the `play()` method:

- If it is `false`: that means that the audio started.
- If it is `true`: it means that the audio didn't start (and you'll have to show the play button instead of the pause button)

This would be the code (replace the images for the right ones):

```
var audio, playbtn, mutebtn, seek_bar;
function initAudioPlayer(){
    audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3";
    audio.loop = true;
    audio.play();

    // Set object references
    playbtn = document.getElementById("playpausebtn");

    // if it's not playing after calling play(), show the other icon
    if(audio.paused) {
        playbtn.style.background = "url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/e/5/a/2/1206570547560908424akiross_Audio_Button_Set_4.svg.thumb.png) no-repeat";        
    }

    // Add Event Handling
    playbtn.addEventListener("click",playPause);
    // Functions
    function playPause(){
        if(audio.paused){
            audio.play();
            playbtn.style.background = "url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/c/e/f/2/1206570536270669982akiross_Audio_Button_Set_1.svg.thumb.png) no-repeat";
        } else {
            audio.pause();
            playbtn.style.background = "url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/e/5/a/2/1206570547560908424akiross_Audio_Button_Set_4.svg.thumb.png) no-repeat";
        }
    }

}
window.addEventListener("load", initAudioPlayer);
```

You can see it working on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LbnLu89d/3/

Comment: I'll try it now and see if I can.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RegExp provided by http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ and do wrap the `window.addEventListener("load", initAudioPlayer);` into:

```
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
if (!(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(userAgent) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(userAgent.substr(0, 4)))) {
    window.addEventListener("load", initAudioPlayer);
}
```

Or you can simply use a library that offers more than just checking, like Mobile Detect https://github.com/hgoebl/mobile-detect.js

Comment: It does not work or I have implemented poorly, could edit my code and insert in it which you have made? Thank you very much.

Comment: Tested twice and it should work pretty fine. Just remove the `window.addEventListener("load", initAudioPlayer);` line and insert the code above. Emulate the mobile device in browser (ie. in Chrome Dev Tools) and check if your player starts.

Comment: Your solution also works, both work.I would not know where to stay: D